# System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'Rfi_Id' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid, sql-server-2008-r2

I have looked through the other answers on the site and cannot seem to get this to work.

I am trying to pull data from two tables and load the results into one grid view.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void DisplayReport()
    {
        string l_strsql = "";

        l_strsql = " SELECT t_WebDAG_Rfi.Rfi_Id AS 'RFI ID #', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Record_Id AS 'Record ID', " +
                    " tbl_DemoData.UserPin AS 'User PIN', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Subject, " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Rfi_Status_Type AS 'Status', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Request_By AS 'Initiator', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Request_Date AS 'Date Requested', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.RFI_Comment AS 'Comments', " +
                    " t_WebDAG_Rfi.Form AS 'Form / Survey' " +
                    " FROM t_WebDAG_Rfi " +
                    " FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_DemoData " +
                    " on tbl_DemoData.RecNum=t_WebDAG_Rfi.Record_Id ";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(l_strsql, strConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataRow dr; 

        ds.AcceptChanges();

        grdvwReport.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grdvwReport.DataBind();
```

This is my .aspx table view:

```
<asp:datagrid id="grdvwReport" runat="server" BorderStyle="Outset" 
                BorderColor="Black" Width="800px"
                Height="270px" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="2px" 
                CssClass=".RightLine">
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" BackColor="SteelBlue" Height="10" Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
                <AlternatingItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#DCDCDC"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" Height="10"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Smaller" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderWidth="4px"
                    ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Outset" BackColor="SteelBlue" Height="10" Wrap="True"></HeaderStyle>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Rfi_Id" HeaderText="RFI ID #"><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Record_Id" HeaderText="Record ID"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserPin" HeaderText="User PIN"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Rfi_Status_Type" HeaderText="Status"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Request_By" HeaderText="Initiator"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Request_Date" HeaderText="Date Requested"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RFI_Comment" HeaderText="Comments"></asp:BoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </asp:datagrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're aliasing the columns in your query:

```
t_WebDAG_Rfi.Rfi_Id AS 'RFI ID #'
```

But then you're using the actual column names in your code:

```
DataField="Rfi_Id"
```

Remove the aliases and it should work:

```
t_WebDAG_Rfi.Rfi_Id
```

It looks like you're trying to use the aliases to create human-readable columns.  But that's a job for the UI, not for the query.  And the UI is already doing that.  So just simplify the query by not using all those aliases.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I appreciate the quick response.